# TweetSharp 2.0 search and Geocode

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

I'm trying to get TweetSharp to perform a search on tweets from within a certain area. Unfortunately this always returns 0 results.

```
public IEnumerable<TwitterSearchStatus> Search(string terms)
{
  TwitterSearchResult result = ServiceManager.Instance.service.Search(terms,100);
  IEnumerable<TwitterSearchStatus> returnValue = result.Statuses;
  return returnValue;
}

public IEnumerable<TwitterSearchStatus> SearchGeolocation(string terms)
{
  return Search(terms + "&geocode=51.50788772102843,-0.102996826171875,50mi");
}
```

This seems to generate the query with a & and % characters escaped which the service then does not convert meaning I get the error you must enter a query:

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?test%26geocode%3D51.50788772102843%2C-0.102996826171875%2C50mi

If I run this query with the characters in place it appears to work fine:

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?test&geocode=51.50788772102843,-0.102996826171875,50mi

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You'll have to find another extension method, or write your own, that accepts a separate geocode parameter. As it stands TweetSharp can't distinguish your geocode parameter from part of the search term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get TweetSharp's search to support the geocode parameter by following these steps:

1. Download TweetSharp's [latest source code](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets)
2. Unpack the zip file to a directory (let's call this *tsSource*).
3. Open the TweetSharp solution under the *tsSource\src* folder.
4. In the VS solution explorer, find **_TwitterService.Search.json** in the *.NET 40\TweetSharp\Generated* folder.
5. Insert the following at line 2 in the file: `TwitterSearchResult, "search", Search, string q, string geocode`
6. In solution explorer, right click on **TwitterService.tt** in the *.NET 40\TweetSharp\Generated* folder and select *Run Custom Tool*; Confirm the warning dialog.
7. Build the **TweetSharp** project after code generation is complete.

The TweetSharp.dll assembly located in the *tsSource\bin\lib\4.0* directory will contain the new method.  You would call the new method like so:

```
service.Search("test", "51.50788772102843,-0.102996826171875,50mi");
```

---

Alternatively, you could use [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/) to support your search queries.  Its search feature does not over-escape the querystring parameters, and it should be able to run side by side with TweetSharp.  If you go this route, the search query code would look like this:

```
//reference Twitterizer2.dll

var tokens = new Twitterizer.OAuthTokens {
  ConsumerKey = @"consumerKey",
  ConsumerSecret = @"consumerSecret",
  AccessToken = @"accessToken",
  AccessTokenSecret = @"accessTokenSecret"
};

var response = Twitterizer.TwitterSearch.Search(tokens, "test", 
  new Twitterizer.SearchOptions { 
    GeoCode = "51.50788772102843,-0.102996826171875,50mi" 
  });
if (response.Result != Twitterizer.RequestResult.Success)
  return;

foreach (var status in response.ResponseObject)
{
  Console.WriteLine(status.Text);
}
```

Comment: Excellent thank you for your help your code change worked nicely. I'll have a play with Twitterizer.